# I want to exclude a certain posts in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, wordpress-theming

Hey everyone I am running into a issue where in wordpress I use post__not_in to not display the category of an id 10. I tried this and it seems to still pull the post in. Would you have a solution to have this work. Thanks everyone!

```
<?php
                 $cat_args = array(
             'orderby' => 'post_date',
             'order' => 'DESC',
             'child_of' => 0,
             'post__not_in' => array(10),
                 );

            $categories =   get_categories($cat_args);


            foreach($categories as $category) {
                 echo '<dl>';
                 echo '<h3 class="category-name">' . $category->name.'</h3>';

                    $post_args = array(
                     'numberposts' => -1,
                     'category' => $category->term_id
                 );

                 $posts = get_posts($post_args);

                 foreach($posts as $post) {
                 ?>
                         <dd><a class="article" target="_blank" href="<?php the_field('article_link') ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><span class="news-source"> - <?php the_field('news_source') ?></span><p class="important"><?php the_field('important') ?></p></dd>
                 <?php
                 }
                 //echo '<dd class="view-all"> <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>View all posts in ' . $category->name.'</a></dd>';
                 echo '</dl>';
                 }

                 ?>
```

Comment: If I'm understanding, you want to use `category__not_in` instead of `post__not_in`

Comment: You also may want to use `get_terms()` instead of `get_categories()`

Comment: @git-e-up So I added those in and it seems the post category is still displaying.

Comment: Okay. Sorry. I think you need to use `'exclude' => array(10)` instead of `'category__not_in'=> array(10)`

Comment: @git-e-up It worked great, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work great for me: `'exclude' => array(10)`